# Django Views not cooperating on form submit

Tags: django, django-views

I have 3 buttons that should change the behavior of the videos on the page depending on the chosen dropdowns. But the user chooses a choice from the dropdown, the videos don't cooperate.

This is the front end. When I choose something on for example language, the videos should change, but it doesn't.

[image: This is the front end]

The page ends up on http://localhost:8000/?language=EN&level=LEV&category=CAT then the page breaks

[image]

I tried adding a reverse_url on the views but it still didn't fix the error.

```
def home(request):
  filter_form = AMLVideoFilterForm(request.GET)
  videos = AMLVideo.objects.all()

    category = filter_form.data.get('category')
    if category:
        videos = videos.filter(
            category__exact=category
        )

    language = filter_form.data.get('language')
    if language:
        videos = videos.filter(
            language__exact=language
        )

    level = filter_form.data.get('level')
    if level:
        videos = videos.filter(
            level__exact=level
        )

    videos = videos.order_by("-category", "-language", "-level")

    context = {'videos': videos, 'filter_form': filter_form, 'level': level, 'language': language, 'category': category,}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

The forms.py is:

```
class AMLVideoFilterForm(forms.Form):
    LANGUAGE = [
        ('LAN', 'Language'),
        ('EN', 'English'),
        ('FR', 'French'),
        ('HIN', 'Hindi'),
        ('SPA', 'Spanish'),
        ('GER', 'German'),
    ]

    LEVEL = [
        ('LEV', 'Level'),
        ('BEG', 'Beginner'),
        ('INT', 'Intermediary'),
        ('ADV', 'Advanced'),
    ]

    CATEGORY = [
        ('CAT', 'Category'),
        ('ADN', 'Adventure'),
        ('ANI', 'Animal'),
        ('ENV', 'Environmental'),
        ('MOR', 'Moral'),
        ('FOLK', 'Folktales'),
        ('POE', 'Poems'),
        ('FUN', 'Funny'),
    ]

    language = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=False, 
        choices=LANGUAGE, 
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'onchange' : "this.form.submit()", 
                'class':'button waves-effect waves-light btn mt-10 mb-10 center-align'
                }
            )
        )
    level = forms.ChoiceField(
            required=False, 
            choices=LEVEL, 
            widget=forms.Select(
                attrs={'onchange' : "this.form.submit()", 
                'class':'button waves-effect waves-light btn mt-10 mb-10 center-align'
                }
            )
        )
    category = forms.ChoiceField(
            required=False, 
            choices=CATEGORY, 
            widget=forms.Select(
                attrs={'onchange' : "this.form.submit()", 
                'class':'button waves-effect waves-light btn mt-10 mb-10 center-align'
                }
            )
        )
```

This is on the front end template

```
    <section class="section-padding portfolio-container">
              <div class="container center-align">
                <div class="row">
                  <form method="GET">
                      {{ filter_form }}
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
    </section>
    <!-- VIDEOS -->
    <section class="section-padding">
      <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                  {% if videos %}  
                  {% for v in videos %}
                  {% video v.video as my %}
                      <iframe width="{{ 380 }}" height="{{ 225 }}" src="{{ my.url }}" 
                      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                  {% endvideo %}
                  {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div> <!-- Row -->
      </div> <!-- container -->
    </section>
```

Anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Could you try to set logger to show your sql queries? https://coderwall.com/p/uzhyca/quickly-setup-sql-query-logging-django It will be easier to trace via the query to see is there any issue with the filters

Comment: `{% video v.video as my %}` what is `{% video %}` ? ... also can you add below my code `print(videos)`

Comment: @Moha369 ```{% video %}``` is from django embed video

Comment: @ToanQuocHo added it just now. what does this do?

Comment: That will show SQL queries in your console when you're filter the video. Now try to choose language on your UI and then take a look at your console then copy the sql command and paste it in here. I think I know why but let's see the sql command first.

Comment: WOW ```(0.001) SELECT "pages_amlvideo"."id", "pages_amlvideo"."slug", "pages_amlvideo"."level", "pages_amlvideo"."language", "pages_amlvideo"."category", "pages_amlvideo"."video" FROM "pages_amlvideo" WHERE ("pages_amlvideo"."category" = 'CAT' AND "pages_amlvideo"."language" = 'EN' AND "pages_amlvideo"."level" = 'LEV') ORDER BY "pages_amlvideo"."category" DESC, "pages_amlvideo"."language" DESC, "pages_amlvideo"."level" DESC; args=('CAT', 'EN', 'LEV')```

Comment: Okay, so if you're not select `Category` and `Level` but it still filter `CAT` and `LEV` value. I bet that your data didn't include any video which has category is `CAT` and level is `LEV`. So you could change the choices follow my answer below

Comment: right. it didn't include data from any videos hence not showing any videos

Comment: Yeah, that's because there is no video which have category is `CAT`, language is `EN` and level is `LEV` => your filter return no data => UI is empty

Comment: Thanks man! You've been a great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're not choosing any filter then the value of `CATEGORY` and `LEVEL` should be empty but there are 2 values `CAT` and `LEV`. That's why when you filter your video, there is no data returned.

Try to make your selects value as empty when you're not select it, by change your form like so:

```
class AMLVideoFilterForm(forms.Form):
    LANGUAGE = [
        ('', 'Choose language'),
        ('EN', 'English'),
        ('FR', 'French'),
        ('HIN', 'Hindi'),
        ('SPA', 'Spanish'),
        ('GER', 'German'),
    ]

    LEVEL = [
        ('', 'Choose level'),
        ('BEG', 'Beginner'),
        ('INT', 'Intermediary'),
        ('ADV', 'Advanced'),
    ]

    CATEGORY = [
        ('', 'Choose category'),
        ('ADN', 'Adventure'),
        ('ANI', 'Animal'),
        ('ENV', 'Environmental'),
        ('MOR', 'Moral'),
        ('FOLK', 'Folktales'),
        ('POE', 'Poems'),
        ('FUN', 'Funny'),
    ]
```

Comment: so the problem was the first choice on each subject. Thank you!

Comment: i have a small follow up question. How do I remove the text beside the buttons?

Comment: language = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=False, 
        choices=LANGUAGE,
        label='',
        widget=forms.Select(
            attrs={
                'onchange' : "this.form.submit()", 
                'class':'button waves-effect waves-light btn mt-10 mb-10 center-align'
                }
            )
        )

Comment: @Highcenburg, just need to add label param and set it to empty